# What POD services are available for printing & selling custom card decks?

Tags: online-resources, publishing

I'm designing a card-based role-playing game and I'm looking for an equivalent to [Lulu](http://lulu.com) for printing online cards on demand.

The cards would be either playing cards like Magic or similar, or Tarot cards (big cards).

Any suggestions? Any feedback on the suggested services?

Comment: I think this is on topic (albeit kind of a shot in the dark as to whether or not it'll succeed). You might also have luck at http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: Ok here is the link for the other question, for maintainers, if one day a question can be on several sites : http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3236/on-demand-cards-deck-printing-service

Answer (score 7):

A quick Google search reveals:

[The Game Crafter](http://www.thegamecrafter.com)

[Guild of Blades Retail Group](http://www.guildofblades.com/podcards.php)

From the sites, it sounds like there are some issues with producing cards on demand that lead to a slightly lower quality than traditional publishing.

Unfortunately, I have no personal experience with either product :/

Comment: The Game Crafter seems to look like what I'm looking for, thanks, I'll check. Strange, even now I don't get this one on my google search...

Comment: @Klaim The search I used was "on-demand playing card printing"

Comment: @Klaim Looking into something similar, I came up with both of these too. I sent an inquiry to Guild of Blades and never heard back, and it looks like they're not accepting new clients. A shame, because I like their setup better. Game Crafter looks excellent for prototyping or early runs that might pay for a later traditional print run, and a good built-in store if sticking with POD cards. Mind, I was only looking then—I haven't yet tried Game Crafter personally.

Answer (score 4):

You're in luck. Episode 48 of the [Paper Money podcast](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/id320761040) devotes nearly the whole show to this topic.

Comment: Too bad I will not be able to watch/listen for now. Is there a transcript somewhere?

Comment: Non-iTunes link, with web player: http://www.purplepawn.com/category/papermoney/ (@Klaim)

Comment: Thanks, but that don't solve the fact that I can't listen to anything ;)